# Authorization error (401) in .net core when calling api to api in windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-401

Have 2 Web API's created using .Net Core 2.0 and hosted internally in IIS under windows authentication (anonymous disabled) on same server. Both API's run on same service account as well with appropriate permissions/rolegroups in Active Directory. However, get 401 unauthorized error when consuming one API from the other. Using HTTPClient to make API calls. Note that, it works when accessing the 2nd API endpoint directly via browser but not from another API.

Decorated with Authorize filter in controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ValidRoleGroup")]
```

Start up code in ConfigureServices in both api services as below.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ValidRoleGroup", policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ValidRoleGroup"]));
});

services.AddMvc(configure =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    configure.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
});

services.AddMvc();
services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(c => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
}));

services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

Comment: Just to add, the API's are on same server but different domains.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 errors went away after adding registry entries as described in below article (Method 1)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

Note that the Value data should be your actual domain URL (XXX.com) and not machine name.

Comment: That link is dead... I am getting a 401 when hitting my API using JWT and can't find a solution.